# Manga involving indirect kiss through icecream

Tags: anedoki

Long back I started reading a manga, where in the first chapter, a guy is showed to have a crush on a girl. Then the girl starts eating an ice-cream cone, but for some reason, the guy then gets to eat the same ice-cream. He then thinks that by eating the same ice-cream, he has shared an indirect kiss with the girl. (Maybe the guy ate the ice-cream first, I don't remember exactly.)

I don't know any more details because I never got back to reading it after finishing half of the first chapter. I want to resume it, and see if it is any good. Does anyone know what manga this is?

Comment: When is "long back"?

Comment: About 2 years back, but I think the manga was much older than that.

Comment: Could it have been a crepe instead? They look a lot like icecream cones. Off the top of my head, the first chapter of the Railgun manga has an indirect kissing thing with crepes, but that's 2 girls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you maybe looking for [*Anedoki*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anedoki)? The question is a bit old, but this appears to be the one you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga.SE! Please consider expanding your answer, as we prefer good and detailed answers, instead of one-liners. :)

Comment: Downvoter, please remove your downvote. This answer is useful. 
@Jnat Not sure what else needs to be explained here. One size doesn't fit all. :)

Comment: What I meant by "expanding the answer" was something in the lines of either including an image or specifying in what point in the story it happens (chapter or episode).

Comment: Also, don't be afraid to answer unanswered old questions. We actually have a [Badge](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival) for it :)

Comment: @JNat It's pretty clear from the question that this happened at the beginning of chapter 1. I don't really think it's necessary, but I've edited in an image of the scene.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this happens in Shugo Chara! in episode 33.  Here's a link to a picture of it:

[image]

Comment: I did this on mobile so I couldn't set the picture or link.

Comment: Does this also happen in the manga in the first chapter?

Comment: It doesn't, but this is the closest thing I could find to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am afraid it isn't the one.

Comment: Okay. Sorry I couldn't help more.